# Upload files directly to Amazon S3 from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload files directly to Amazon S3 from ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117810/upload-files-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-asp-net-application)

My ASP.NET MVC application will take a lot of bandwidth and storage space. How can I setup an ASP.NET upload page so the file the user uploaded will go straight to Amazon S3 without using my web server's storage and bandwidth?

Comment: This is a duplicate, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

[You can write a form that posts directly to Amazon's S3 service via HTML POST.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html)  That should prevent you from needing the bandwidth on your end, assuming you need to do no processing of the content yourself before sending it to S3.