# Upload large files to S3 with resume support

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, multipart

(I'm new to Amazon AWS/S3, so please bear with me)

My ultimate goal is to allow my users to upload files to S3 using their web browser, my requirements are:

1. I  must handle large files (2GB+)
2. I must support pause/resume with progress indicator
3. (Optional but desirable!) Ability to resume upload if connection temporarily drops out

**My two-part question is:**

- I've read about the S3 multipart upload but it's not clear how can I
  implement the pause/resume for webbrowser-based uploads.

Is it even possible to do this for large files? If so how?

- Should I upload files to EC2 then move them to S3 once I'm done? Can
  I (securely) upload files directly to S3 instead of using a temp. webserver?

If it's possible to upload directly to S3, how can I handle pause/resume?

**PS. I'm using PHP 5.2+**

Comment: Yes, you can sercurely let your visitors upload to S3, without giving away your Amazon AWS credentials, by creating a HMAC signature signature on your server, which then is used by the visitor's browser to upload directly to S3. Have a look here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html However, I do not know if that is possible to combine with pause/resume-upload.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Update 20150527

The meanwhile available [AWS SDK for JavaScript (in the Browser)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/index.html) supports Amazon S3, including a class [ManagedUpload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html) to support the multipart upload aspects of the use case at hand (see preceding update for more on this). It might now be the best solution for your scenario accordingly, see e.g. [Uploading a local file using the File API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Uploading_a_local_file_using_the_File_API) for a concise example that uses the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) in turn - the introductory blog post [Announcing the Amazon S3 Managed Uploader in the AWS SDK for JavaScript](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx3EQZP53BODXWF/Announcing-the-Amazon-S3-Managed-Uploader-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript) provides more details about this SDK feature.

#### Update 20120412

My initial answer apparently missed the main point, so to clarify:

If you want to do browser based upload via simple HTML forms, you are constrained to using the [POST Object operation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html), which *adds an object to a specified bucket using HTML forms*:

> POST is an alternate form of PUT that enables browser-based uploads as
>   a way of putting objects in buckets. Parameters that are passed to PUT
>   via HTTP Headers are instead passed as form fields to POST in the
>   multipart/form-data encoded message body. [...]

The upload is handled in a single operation here, thus doesn't support pause/resume and limits you to the original maximum object size *of 5 gigabytes (GB) or less*.

You can only overcome both limitations by [Using the REST API for Multipart Upload instead](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html), which is in turn used by SDKs like the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) to implement this functionality.

This obviously requires a server (e.g. on EC2) to handle the operation initiated via the browser (which allows you to facilitate [S3 Bucket Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html) and/or [IAM Policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html) for access control easily as well).

The one alternative might be using a JavaScript library and performing this client side, see e.g. [jQuery Upload Progress and AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856917/jquery-upload-progress-and-ajax-file-upload) for an initial pointer. <strike>Unfortunately there is no canonical JavaScript SDK for AWS available ([aws-lib](https://github.com/livelycode/aws-lib) surprisingly doesn't even support S3 yet) - apparently some forks of [knox](https://github.com/learnboost/knox) have added multipart upload, see e.g. [slakis's fork](https://github.com/slaskis/knox), I haven't used either of these for the use case at hand though.</strike>

---

#### Initial Answer

> If it's possible to upload [large files] directly to S3, how can I handle
>   pause/resume?

The [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) supports uploading large files to Amazon S3 by means of the [Low-Level PHP API for Multipart Upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingLLmpuPHP.html):

> The AWS SDK for PHP exposes a low-level API that closely resembles the
>   Amazon S3 REST API for multipart upload (see Using the REST API for
>   Multipart Upload ). **Use the low-level API when you need to pause and
>   resume multipart uploads, vary part sizes during the upload, or do not
>   know the size of the data in advance**. Use the high-level API (see
>   Using the High-Level PHP API for Multipart Upload) whenever you don't
>   have these requirements. *[emphasis mine]*

Amazon S3 can handle objects *from 1 byte all the way to 5 terabytes (TB)*, see the respective introductory post [Amazon S3 - Object Size Limit Now 5 TB](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/12/amazon-s3-object-size-limit.html):

> [...] Now customers can store extremely
>   large files as single objects, which greatly simplifies their storage
>   experience. Amazon S3 does the bookkeeping behind the scenes for our
>   customers, so you can now GET that large object just like you would
>   any other Amazon S3 object.
>
> In order to store larger objects you would use the new [Multipart Upload API](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html) that I blogged about last month to upload the object in
>   parts. [...]

Comment: But would it be possible to port this multipart stuff into javascript (or flash/actionscript) and do it in the browser, without giving away aws credentials?

Comment: Thank you Steffen, but my understanding is that the low level doesn't allow to pass from client to S3 directly (without web server), at least that's what the [PHP example](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFilePHP.html) shows if I'm correct...am I missing something here?

Comment: @style-sheets: I've apparently missed the main point in my initial answer and updated it accordingly now, sorry for being misleading!

Comment: @AlfredGodoy: It should  work in principle, insofar the REST API supports pre-signed URLs for `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE`; I haven't tried this myself yet for the use case at hand though.

Comment: @SteffenOpel: a lot of good info, thank you! Just to make sure, by saying `This requires a server (e.g. on EC2) to handle the operation initiated via the browser`; do you mean executing the PHP code or uploading the temporary file? Obviously I'm going to use PHP anyway, what I'd like to avoid is the upload to EC2 and then to S3

Comment: @style-sheets: There is no way to avoid this other than exploring a client side JavaScript solution using the S3 REST API directly; I don't think it is much of a problem cost/performance wise, insofar EC2 to S3 connections are rather fast and free within one region. Obviously this approach offloads the pause/resume problem to HTML forms though, which again requires JavaScript as well as modern browsers supporting the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) - maybe [How to resume a paused or broken file upload](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/04/resumeupload/) can get you started in case.

Comment: @style-sheets I believe you can accomplish this using a browser plugin like flash, silverlight or java and directly using the REST API. I currently use a silverlight plugin to upload large files (up to 5GB) directly to S3. I haven't implement pause/resume don't use the S3 large file support but it should be possible. Using a plugin is the only way to achieve broad browser coverage. Checkout this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478799/upload-file-directly-to-s3-with-progress-bar. There are lots of links there to various free and not free plugins.

Comment: If that is the case, Is there a plugin or demo app with pause/resume functionality available?

Comment: There is an official [JS SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/) today. Also, there is an intelligent [multipart upload API](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx3EQZP53BODXWF/Announcing-the-Amazon-S3-Managed-Uploader-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript) available.

Comment: @Alex - thanks for the bump/pointer, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any flash uploaders offering anything more powerful than standard HTTP Post but you could develop your own flash software for the client with co-ordinating software on the server.