# AWS S3 Javascript SDK Resend Request Failure

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-javascript-sdk

I am using AWS S3 Javascript sdk to upload files to my S3 bucket via my browser. I had no problem fetching files or uploading small and even huge files with the multi-part upload normally.

The issue I faced was while uploading a huge file and lost my connection in between. After the connection returned, the request was resend for the remaining parts to be uploaded but failed.

I have attached a screenshot of the failed requests

[image]

Any reason why this fails, or any way this can be handled/resolved?

Comment: when does the "huge file" fail to upload ? whats the file size ?

Comment: The file is about 4.5 MB, split into 2 parts for multipart upload. It does work sometimes, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Can you upload the script somewhere? I can debug it.

Comment: Did you checked this topic? It may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124785/upload-large-files-to-s3-with-resume-support

Comment: CORS - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ ?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to upload? It might help identifying the issue.

Answer (score 6):

When you are uploading a huge set of data, you can try including a class ManagedUpload for multi-part uploading. You need to specify the bucket size, however. A sample code of this fromt the documentation would be:

```
var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
  partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1,
  params: {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream}
});
```

Where, the `partSize` (Number), by default, the value is `5mb` is the size in bytes for each individual part to be uploads.

There's also an open source project in GitHub: [AWS S3 Multipart Upload from Browser](https://github.com/ienzam/s3-multipart-upload-browser), which is written in JavaScript and PHP to make huge files to be uploaded in Amazon S3 server directly, in chunks of 5 MB, so it is resumable and recovers easily from error.

Guessing that to use the above plugin, you might have to use PHP. There's also a limit on maximum upload size per file. Please do have a look at it.