# Upload images to Amazon S3 using HTML form?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Appharbor as a free hosting for my application. I have a simple "path image uploader" to a specific folder in my project, and when using Appharbor it will store it normally but the images will get deleted everytime I push the project.

I've search for a solution and I end up everytime getting redirected to a cloud storage such as Amazon S3 which is super cheap.

So I created an account and saw that you can actually upload images and get a hyperlink of the file.

But now I can't really find a way to make my HTML form to POST/upload images to my "bucket" folder in the Amazon S3.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using ASP.NET MVC 4 C#?

Comment: you can try to leverage 3rd party service, e.g. [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browser-based uploads to AWS](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html). Also see [this other, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117810/upload-files-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-asp-net-application).

Comment: I see, I've tried that and now I'm stuck at: `<Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message>` when I just have one `type="file"` with `id="file"`

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Might be the issue raised [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jquery-fileupload/r0aEXHk22xQ/K2GcRkA4RMIJ). In which case, it's a jQuery problem.