# Upload files directly to AWS S3 storage using browser rather via asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We need to work on asp.net application which will allow upload/download of files to AWS S3 storage bucket.

All contents stored in bucket are non-public.

We figured files can be downloaded directly from AWS S3 storage using  `pre-signed urls`.

We are also trying to figure out a way by which we can upload files also directly to AWS S3 storage bucket.

After looking for sometime we found below article but this article is quite old and i am not able to figure out how actually it works or its latest version.

Is there a better way of uploading files directly from client browser.

Pointer to  asp.net code snipped or article would be nice start

Comment: Following link not that help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117810/upload-files-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-asp-net-application

Comment: Your perception of its helpfulness notwithstanding, I'm afraid that's the correct answer, leading directly to the step-by-step documentation... and this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could authenticate your users with [cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), [either with a login provider or with your own identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html).

Then, your client browser can use `GetCredentialsForIdentity` to retrieve temporary AWS credentials associated with [a role that you configure to have permissions to write in S3](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies).

Use the AWS javascript SDK to communicate with the S3 API.